# PHP Salesforce. How would you Format a Picklist That is Restricted to only select one value

Tags: php, laravel, api, salesforce

I need to figure out how to add a picklist value that is restricted to one value. So if I had a selection Between Red, Green, Blue. How would I pass that value as a pick list in a Post. Consider the following...

If Color_c is a picklist that has the option of Red, Green, and Blue. How would I selected just Blue? The labels and values are literally the same.

I am using https://github.com/omniphx/forrest

The following is the result if I just a straight String value.

`INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY:`

```
Forrest::sobjects('Car__c', [
    'method' => 'post',
    'body' => [
        // Step 1
        'Name' => 'Mustang',
        'Color_c' => 'Blue',
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Sforce-Auto-Assign' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    ]

]);
```

I am expecting a result.